# Unable to match distance computed in geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

**As per geocoder official doc:**

Distance between Eiffel Tower and Empire State Building

```
Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([47.858205,2.294359], [40.748433,-73.985655])
```

=> **3619.77359999382** # in configured units (default miles)

```
def geodistance
   render json: Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([47.858205,2.294359], [40.748433,-73.985655])
end
```

**In my case** I am getting the value to be:

=> **3648.3340765758867**

Unit configurations are unchanged, not sure what can go wrong!

Comment: Are you saying that both results are coming from `Geocoder` or is your result calculated a different way?

Comment: The former one (3619.77359999382) is as per this doc: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder and 3648.3340765758867 is when I run

Comment: Try putting `Geocoder::Calculations.di....` into a variable and print it. Then pass that variable to `render json: <variable>` and compare the difference

Comment: I believe the second query is the correct distance. Does your first query use SQLite, i.e. performed in a dev environment with a SQLite DB? [When using SQLite, Geocoder will automatically use a less accurate algorithm for finding objects near a given point.](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/c1cbcf6f66d37ac1df02788512d35ea8cb1d17ff/README.md#distance-queries-in-sqlite)

Comment: Putting into variable and printing gives 3648.3340765758867 as well

Comment: @BigRon  I am using Postgres and Postgis. First query is as per the official Geocoder doc illustrations.

Comment: @srs [Postgis is not compatible with Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/261#issuecomment-7042787) for distance queries

Comment: @BigRon Postgis is an extension of Postgres and I assume it should not be the fault here? as by default it should access. I am using geocoded_by etc method in model and datatype as: float and string as opposed to postgis data types for rgeo: st_point etc.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @srs I know `Postgis` is an extension of `Postgres`. With `Postgis` you CAN still perform `geocoded_by`; however, you cannot perform distance calculations via `Geocoder`. Distance calculations must be performed in an alternate manner, i.e. [rgeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo)

Comment: @Big Can you be little more precise? I am not storing any Postgis datatypes in my active record for this model. For this model, datatypes are lat: float, long: float and last_location:string. If I use Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([47.858205,2.294359], [40.748433,-73.985655]) why it will be a problem this case?

Comment: @srs aah. I hear you. You are not trying to use a Postgis datatype at all... so that should be irrelevant.

Comment: That's right @Big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read me](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) doc distance value :=> 3619.77359999382 is [outdated](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/1211).

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'geocoder'
true
irb(main):002:0> Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([47.858205,2.294359], [40.748433,-73.985655])
3648.3340765758867
```

This one is my sample output.

IMO: Might be that you used different ruby or gem versions in each case or something...
It would be nice to know in which environments did both of this code samples execute.

Use the [source](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/b5af9506a3462b57af0cecef597d2569e204c967/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb), Luke!

#### EDIT:

Might be something in this part of code:

```
a = (Math.sin(dlat / 2))**2 + Math.cos(point1[0]) *
          (Math.sin(dlon / 2))**2 * Math.cos(point2[0])
c = 2 * Math.atan2( Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
c * earth_radius(options[:units])
```

Comment: Thanks @Aitzhan. 3648.3340765758867 is also what I got when running. The other one is as per the document and I think it's not up to date anymore.

Comment: I checked the source and the `distance_between()` method [hasn't even been touched in 6 years](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blame/b5af9506a3462b57af0cecef597d2569e204c967/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb#L84) according to GitHub. It's odd that their documentation does not seem to match.

Comment: Can you cross check with these points as well: Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([12.936992, 77.627002], [12.848925, 77.651733])          Result I got: 6.3087039709946735

Comment: got: 6.3087039709946735

Comment: Exactly what I thought it would be. Now the best part is even if we assume both our environment setups are alright, this value (6.3087039709946735, in miles or 10.152874887374361 in kms) does not match with the direction feature of Google Map, GMap points distance is 13.9 KMs. since I am adding nearby users feature in my project, where I say the user is 10 kms away and in google map it is 13.9 kms away. it might lead to a huge frustration. Someone please share some lights on how to match geocoder distance with GMap direction values. @Aitzhan Can you also verify my google map findings

Comment: Just a note: Geocoder is using the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for calculating distance. Unfortunately, this is only an approximation as it is only exact for spherical objects and the planet is actually slightly fatter around the equator than it is pole-to-pole. It may well be that the Google formulas use a more accurate model of the Earth.

Comment: @srs If you want your distance calculation to match the GMap directions (distance dependent on roadways or other path of travel), why don't you use Google Maps API to calculate the directional distance? Or there are opensource options like [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.9.1/api/#route-service). I updated this with the correct link to OSRM routing.

Comment: Here is your path of travel distance via OSRM, which closely matches the path of travel via GMaps: http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/77.627002,12.936992;77.651733,12.848925?overview=false. The resulting distance in OSRM is 13.1km. Again, this is path of travel, not the spherical distance between two points on the globe.

Comment: Nice note @Phylogenesis. Surely BigRon, I will give a deep dive, if someone else interestingly comes up with any other way to work around, please care to share.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't realise you were comparing the Geocoder output with that of a routing engine's output. Geocoder is using "[as the crow flies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_crow_flies)" distance, whereas things like OSRM will calculate distance as allowed by the road network.

Comment: I thought, it is using Google Api for lookup. but that is for geocoding only. Any suggestions on best practices to get distance via road network

Comment: [Best practices to get distance via road network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485363/unable-to-match-distance-computed-in-geocoder#comment77936852_45485861)